# Elasticsearch fuzzy query and match with fuzziness

Tags: elasticsearch

So i saw these two queries. 
First one is match with fuzziness option

```
{
    "query": {
       "match": {
         "user": {
           "query": "ki",
           "fuzziness": "AUTO"
         }
       }
    }
}
```

Second one is normal fuzzy search

```
{
"query": {
    "fuzzy": {
        "user": {
            "value": "ki"
         }
      }
   } 
}
```

Result is pretty much the same. But my question is, does the query really does the same structure? and which one to use for fuzziness best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example the results are the same. However, the fuzzy query behaves like a term query, so it does not perform analysis beforehand, whereas the match query does.

So if you searched for an address field containing `pigeon street` and indexed with a standard analyser, this query would work

```
GET my-index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "address": {
                "query": "wigeon street",
                "fuzziness": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but this one would not:

```
GET my-index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "fuzzy": {
            "address": {
                "value": "wigeon street"
            }
        }
    }
}
```